# sale automatic workflow OCA odoo

Tags: automation, odoo, odoo-9

I need to automate Odoo's sales process for a 1 person sales team.
The OCA sale automatic workflow module seems ideal:

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/sale_automatic_workflow/

I have tried the demo, setting up a new automatic workflow and checking all the checkboxes:

Validate Order

Confirm and Transfer Picking

Create Invoice

Validate Invoice

Register Payment

Sale Done

so that a confirmed sales order will automatically validate it, get the products out of the warehouse, create the invoice, validate it, mark it as paid and mark the sale done.

However, when I create a new sales order and choose the automatic workflow option, once I save it or confirm it, it does nothing.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: This module is working with a cron job, is it running? Was the created worklflow set on the order? There is a new tab for that on the sales order form.

Comment: Yes, the created workflow was set on the new tab. However I didn't notice the cron job. It doesn't make much sense to me that that this automated workflow be triggered by a cron job, which would have to poll all new objects in the database to see if they match the automated workflow and trigger it, rather than it being triggered by the save or validate action of the objects. Can you indicate where the cron job is configured/started? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Activate developer mode and look under settings/technical

Comment: Ok. Yes the cron job was active and now I get it. It WAS working, but it may take up to a minute for the automatic workflow to kick in based on the fact that this runs on a cron job! It doesn't make any sense to me to do it this way. Is there any way to fire the cron job on sale order save or validation? I would accept such an answer since it would solve the problem.

Comment: I had created on model sale.workflow.process.ept which runs at every 1 minute but it didn't affect my sale order